# How do I style input type="number"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's the code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/v2tkk26u/3/

```
<input type="number" id="numeric" size="1"/>
```

I want the input to be a smaller size (since it will hold only one number) but changing the size attribute seems to have no effect on it.

Also, the up down arrows are too small, especially when I add padding to the input. I want to make them bigger and always stay displayed, not just on hover (to make them mobile friendly).

Comment: NOTE: The arrows appearing only on hover is a Google Chrome thing. In Firefox they are always present. In IE11, they do not exist.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `width` and `height` properties in CSS like so. This for example will set the `width` and `height` each to `10px`. Of course you can change it to whatever size you want.

```
#numeric {
    color:blue;
    font-size:1.1em;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
```

**EDIT**

Didn't catch that you were trying to style input `type="number"`. I highly suggest reading [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) to read more about CSS attribute selectors. But below I will summarize and relate it back to your question.

So in your example if you want to style all `input` HTML tags where `type="number"` you can do something like the following.

```
input[type="number"] {
    color:blue;
    font-size:1.1em;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
```

If you would like to select all elements (not just `input` elements) where `type="number"` you can do the following.

```
[type~="number"] {
    color:blue;
    font-size:1.1em;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: The question clearly asked about styling `<input>` elements with `type=“number”`, not whatever element is `id="numeric"`.  You  have done the latter, not the former.

Comment: @Makyen You are correct. Will work on editing my answer now.

Comment: @Makyen Thanks for catching that. Just edited my answer. Let me know if you have any other tips or advice or anything else I didn't catch.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @CharlieFish's answer, you may want to add some code to restrict the element to only 1 character. Use the `min` and `max` element to restrict them from entering a number in that range.

As well as that, you may want to have them only be able to type 1 number. This code will allow you to do that:

```
document.getElementById('numeric').oninput = function () {
    if (this.value.length > 1) {
        this.value = this.value.slice(0,1); 
    }
}
```

See the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v2tkk26u/5/)

Comment: Nice addition. I interpreted it to mean styling of the element but good point.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this one..

```
body {
  background:yellow;
}
 #numeric {
   color:blue;
   font-size:1.1em;
   border-radius:5px;
   padding: 5px;
   height:20px;
   width:50px;
 }
 input[type=number] {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0 8px;
}
```